# Pycharm: Flask not recognized in venv "zsh: command not found: flask"

Tags: unix, flask, terminal, python-venv

I am rubbing my head not understand why Pycharm can recognize flask with venev as project interpreter, while terminal can't. I tried to look it up online but failed.

[Project interpreter in Pycharm with flask showing up installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dag1R.png)
[venv in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZ1H.png)

Comment: Show us a project structure as well as the steps you make in the terminal to achieve your end result.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the images you sent, I ended up with the following conclusion.

The terminal successfully recognized the virtual environment of your project, i.e. `venv`. However, you don t have the flask module installed in that virtual environment, that s why you get the error `flask: command not found`.

To see that go into your terminal, inside the virtual environment and type `pip list` to see all the available libraries. If you don t have `Flask` in there just type `pip install flask`.

Comment: I got it! My project was running on virtual environment. Bummer!! LOL